# python3 flask: how to display the json result in html

Tags: python-3.x, web, flask

Now I want to send the json data to html, I just display the dictionary data(json), How to display the value of dictionary in the html.
The python code is:

```
@app.route('/upload', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def upload():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        img_file = request.files['img_file']
        if img_file and allowed_file(img_file.filename):
            filename = secure_filename(img_file.filename)
            img_file.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename))
            raw_img_url = './static/asset/uploads/' + filename
            result_img_url = './static/asset/output/Line/' + filename

            ratio = check_banner(filename)
            result_dict = {'result': ratio}

            return  render_template("upload.html", result_img_url=result_img_url, result=json.dumps(result_dict))
        else:
            return ''' ok</p> '''
    else:
        return redirect(url_for('upload'))
```

The html code:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block content %}

<form method="post" action="/upload" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input type="file" id="img_file" name="img_file" class="col-sm-4">
  <input type="submit" value="check" class="btn">
</form>

<p>
{% if result_img_url %}
    <img src="{{ result_img_url }}" width='400' height='350'>
{% endif %}
</p>

<ul>

<li>{{result}}</li>

</ul>


{% endblock %}
```

But the result html is, but I just want to show the value of result :

[image: result html]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to pass only one parameter in `result`, you may change `result_dict = {'result': ratio}` to `result = ratio`.

It will show only the result in the page:

[image: show only value]

Comment: OK thanks!, after I do this, I want to do:{% if result <= 0.2 and (size is 1) %}
<th> Pass </th>
<th> {{ type(result) }} </th>
{% elif result = 0.24 and (size is 1) %}
<th> Need Check </th>
{% (elif result > 0.24 and size is 1) or (size is 0) %}
<th> no pass </th>
</p>

Comment: but there is error: jinja2.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError: expected token 'name', got 'integer'

Comment: @tktktk0711, if this answer solves the queries in scope of the question please accept it. For further queries, add a separate question with details of the template and error traceback. Asking questions in comments and answering them in comments are not advised in Stackoverflow. :)